# Sci-fi movie where a guy loses a girl, tries to hijack a train, finds the girl but she leaves him

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie that I saw some years ago.

The movie starts with a man and woman (both have dark hair) who are running in crowded area on their way to going through a border security passage.

The women passes through, but since they are hunted, the man is captured.

Later in the movie the man takes a job for an evil guy to bring some valuable "minerals" or cylinder tubes. They are going to hijack a train (the train is going on a rail in the sky) but they fail the mission.

They get one more chance from this evil guy. It appears he's in a relationship with this girl the man has been looking for. Thanks to the girl, the man gets another chance but only if she supervises him on the mission.

I don't remember how they got the valuable package but I think they swap it after they got it. The real thing is given to some poor people while the fake one is given to the evil guy.

If I remember correctly the woman kills the evil guy.

She leaves the guy and travels away in a ship that looks like a flipped boot, or a upside down "L" letter aka "˥"

I got the impression it could be a sequel to this movie but don't remember if there is.

I thought it could be a Star Wars or Marvel movie but I haven't found it. I think it's made from 2010 or later.

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks. Somewhere my brain didn't want to connect it to that movie and thought it was two different movies (I only remember Solo freeing Chewbacca in Solo). Thanks for your time and help. Much appreciated :)!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This appears to be [*Solo: A Star Wars Story*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3778644/) (2018), which is the origin story of Han Solo.

The guy is a young Han Solo; the girl is Qi'ra.  You can read a fair summary of the plot on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story).

> On the planet Corellia, orphans Han and Qi'ra escape a local gang. They bribe an Imperial officer with stolen starship fuel, known as coaxium, for passage on a transport, but Qi'ra is captured before she can board. Han vows to return for her and joins the Imperial Navy as a flight cadet, being given the surname "Solo".
>
> Three years later, Han is serving as an infantryman on Mimban following his expulsion from the Imperial Flight Academy for insubordination. He encounters a group of criminals posing as Imperial soldiers, led by Tobias Beckett. Han attempts to blackmail Beckett into letting him join the gang, but Beckett has him arrested and thrown into a pit to be fed to a Wookiee prisoner named Chewbacca. Able to understand Chewbacca's language, Han persuades him to cooperate to escape. Beckett, aware of the usefulness of a Wookiee's strength, rescues and enlists them in the gang to steal a shipment of coaxium on Vandor-1. The plan fails when the Cloud Riders, a band of marauders led by Enfys Nest, arrive to hijack the shipment. The resulting chaos leads to the destruction of the coaxium and the deaths of Beckett's wife Val and another crewman, Rio.
>
> Beckett reveals that he was ordered to steal the shipment for Dryden Vos, a high-ranking crime boss in the Crimson Dawn syndicate. Han and Chewbacca volunteer to help him steal another shipment to repay the debt so that Vos will not kill him. They travel to Vos's yacht where Han finds Qi'ra, who has joined Crimson Dawn as Vos's top lieutenant.